# How could I DRY this while loop?

Tags: ruby, loops, dry

I need to DRY this code but I don't know how.

I tried to dry the if condition but I don't know how to put the while in this.

```
def sum_with_while(min, max)
  # CONSTRAINT: you should use a while..end structure
  array = (min..max).to_a
  sum = 0
  count = 0
  if min > max
    return -1
  else
    while count < array.length
      sum += array[count]
      count += 1
    end
  end

  return sum
end
```

Comment: You can get rid of the if block and just have guard clause that return -1 at the top of the method e.g. `return -1 if <some clause>`. No need to check the clause after that, you are only left with the while statement

Comment: What about `(min..max).sum`? Yes there is no `while`...

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to stack overflow!

Firstly, I should point out that "DRY" stands for "Don't Repeat Yourself". Since there's no repetition here, that's not really the problem with this code.

The biggest issue here is it's unrubyish. The ruby community has certain things it approves of, and certain things it avoids. That said, `while` loops are themselves considered bad ruby, so if you've been told to write it with a while loop, I'm guessing you're trying to get us to do your homework for you.

So I'm going to give you a couple of things to do a web search for that will help start you off:

- ruby guard clauses - this will reduce your `if-else-end` into a simple `if`
- ruby array pop - you can do `while item = array.pop` - since pop returns nil once the array is empty, you don't need a count. Again, bad ruby to do this... but maybe consider `while array.any?`
- ruby implicit method return - generally we avoid commands we don't need

It's worth noting that using the techniques above, you can get the content of the method down to 7 reasonably readable lines. If you're allowed to use `.inject` or `.sum` instead of `while`, this whole method becomes 2 lines.

(as [HP_hovercraft](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57081215/208769) points out, the ternary operator reduces this down to 1 line. On production code, I'd be tempted to leave it as 2 lines for readability - but that's just personal preference)

Answer (score 1):

You can put the whole thing in one line with a ternary:

```
def sum_with_while(min, max)
  min > max ? -1 : [*(min..max)].inject(0){|sum,x| sum + x }
end
```

Comment: Good point. Funny, I always forget you can do `[*(min..max)]` - not quite as readable as `to_a`, but a cool addition. That said, both `inject` and `sum` will work on Ranges too, so actually arrayifying the range isn't required, Also, you could replace the whole inject statement with either `.inject(&:+)` or `.sum`...

Comment: @user208769 You're right, sum would make this even shorter!

Answer (score 1):

This is one option, cleaning up your code, see comments:

```
def sum_with_while(range) # pass a range
  array = range.to_a
  sum, count = 0, 0 # parallel assignment
  while count < array.length
    sum += array[count]
    count += 1
  end
  sum # no need to return
end


sum_with_while(10..20)
#=> 165
```

---

More Rubyish:

```
(min..max).sum
```

Comment: Refactoring the original code does seem kind of pointless because, as you illustrate, the Ruby solution is extremely small and simple. The original code seems to be tackling the problem from the wrong direction.

Comment: Very close to my 7-line solution - except rather than using parallel assignment, I dropped `count` altogether and used `Array#pop`. Also, I presumed that maintaining the method signature was important, as was returning -1 should the min, max be the wrong way around...

Answer (score 1):

**Rule 1: Choose the right algorithm.**

You wish to compute an *arithmetic series*.<sup>1</sup>

```
def sum_with_while(min, max)
  max >= min ? (max-min+1)*(min+max)/2 : -1   
end
```

```
sum_with_while(4, 4)
  #=> 4 
sum_with_while(4, 6)
  #=> 15 
sum_with_while(101, 9999999999999)
  #=> 49999999999994999999994950
```

<sup>1. An arithmetic series is the sum of the elements of an arithmetic sequence. Each term of the latter is computed from the previous one by adding a fixed constant `n` (possibly negative). Here`max-min+1` is the number of terms in the sequence and `(min+max)/2`, if `(min+max)` is even, is the average of the values in the sequence. As `(max-min+1)*(min+max)` is even, this works when `(min+max)` is odd as well.</sup>

Comment: Haha... beautifully confusing! I'm guessing this is an absolute beginner, trying to understand what that while loop is[n't] doing could take them a while ;)

Comment: Haha, this would be a good question to ask in an interview for junior dev: Remove the redundant lines of code from this function.

Comment: @HPHovercraft and other readers: my initial reading was that a `while` loop was required, but I now see that's not the case, so I've done an edit. "Haha" in the previous comments were a response to me having written `while true; return (max-min+1)*(min+max)/2; end`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I think you were right first time - I believe this to be OP's homework, and as per the comment in their code snippet, they have been told that they must use a `while` loop. So I think that your original answer technically fulfils the bonkers requirement with an equally bonkers implementation - I love it :D